# Xarray rolling mean with weights

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

When I do running / rolling mean with weights in numpy, I e.g. do something like this:

```
data = np.random.random(100)  # Example data...
weights = np.array([1, 2, 1])
data_m = np.convolve(data, weights/float(np.sum(weights)), "same")
```

And then replace data_m[0] and data_m[-1] with e.g. nans, depending on application.

Something alike can be done with xarray. What I do (in this case) is

```
xr.DataArray(data).rolling(dim_0=3, center=True).mean(dim="dim_0")
```

But this corresponds to the weights

```
weights = np.array([1, 1, 1])
```

in the numpy example. How would I apply other weights, when using xarray?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The weighted-rolling-mean is not yet implemented in xarray.

The following does almost the same thing but it would be quite slow.
I think the use of np.convolve is the current best choice.

```
def weighted_sum(x, axis):
    weight = [1, 2, 1]
    if x.shape[axis] == 3:
        return np.sum(x * weight, axis=axis)
    else:
        return np.nan

da.rolling(dim_0=3, center=True).reduce(weighted_sum)
```

Currently, we are working to support more flexible (and faster) rolling operations. See https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/1837

EDIT:

With xarray=0.10.2, weighted rolling mean can be computed as follows,

```
weight = xr.DataArray([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], dims=['window'])
da.rolling(dim_0=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)
```

where `construct` method constructs a view of the rolling object, where the window dimension (named `window` in the above example) is attatched to the last position.
inner product with the weight array gives the weighted sum along the window dimension.

Comment: not sure, but I think you need to divide by the sum of the weights, right?
da.rolling(dim_0=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)/weight.sum()

Answer (score 4):

If you want a `Gaussian`-like filter, another hack is to apply the rolling mean recursively.

Infinite recursions of the boxcar filter (i.e., our rolling mean) becomes a Gaussian filter.
See [B-spline in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) for the detail.

Example:

```
x = xr.DataArray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dims=['x'])

# With window=2
tmp = x
plt.plot(tmp, '-ok', label='original')
for i in range(3):
    tmp = tmp.rolling(x=2, min_periods=1).mean()
    plt.plot(tmp, '-o', label='{}-times'.format(i+1))
plt.legend()
```

[image: recursive rolling mean with window size 2]

```
# with window=3, center=True
tmp = x
plt.plot(tmp, '--ok', label='original')
for i in range(3):
    tmp = tmp.rolling(x=3, center=True, min_periods=1).mean()
    plt.plot(tmp, '-o', label='{}-times'.format(i+1))
plt.legend()
```

[image: recursive rolling mean with window size 3 with the centralization]

Note: if you want to centralize the result, use the odd window size.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific for the [1,2,1] weights, and it requires two steps, so it is not the best solution, but it is quite quick:

```
dim_name = "dim_0"
da_mean = da.rolling(**{dim_name: 3, "center": True}).mean(dim=dim_name)
da_mean = (3 * da_mean + da) / 4.  # Expand it, and add the middle value.
```