# xarray: simple weighted rolling mean example using .construct()

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

Xarray can do weighted rolling mean via the `.construct()` object as stated in answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510784/xarray-rolling-mean-with-weights) and also in the [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#rolling-window-operations).

The weighted rolling mean example in the docs doesn't quite look right as it seems to give the same answer as the ordinary rolling mean.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

arr = xr.DataArray(np.arange(0, 7.5, 0.5).reshape(3, 5),
...                dims=('x', 'y'))
arr.rolling(y=3, center=True).mean()
#<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 5)>
#array([[nan, 0.5, 1. , 1.5, nan],
#       [nan, 3. , 3.5, 4. , nan],
#       [nan, 5.5, 6. , 6.5, nan]])
#Dimensions without coordinates: x, y

weight = xr.DataArray([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], dims=['window'])
arr.rolling(y=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)
#<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 5)>
#array([[nan, 0.5, 1. , 1.5, nan],
#       [nan, 3. , 3.5, 4. , nan],
#       [nan, 5.5, 6. , 6.5, nan]])
#Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
```

Here is a more simple example which I would like to get the syntax right on:

```
da = xr.DataArray(np.arange(1,6), dims='x')
da.rolling(x=3, center=True).mean()
#<xarray.DataArray (x: 5)>
#array([nan,  2.,  3.,  4., nan])
#Dimensions without coordinates: x

weight = xr.DataArray([0.5, 1, 0.5], dims=['window'])
da.rolling(x=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)
#<xarray.DataArray (x: 5)>
#array([nan,  4.,  6.,  8., nan])
#Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

It returns 4, 6, 8. I thought it would do:

```
(1 x 0.5) + (2 x 1) + (3 x 0.5) / 3 = 4/3
(2 x 0.5) + (3 x 1) + (4 x 0.5) / 3 = 2
(3 x 0.5) + (4 x 1) + (5 x 0.5) / 3 = 8/3
1.33, 2. 2.66
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you use evenly spaced data for `arr`.
Therefore, the weighted mean (with [0.25, 5, 0.25]) will be the same as the simple `mean`.

If you consider non-linear data, the result differs

```
In [50]: arr = xr.DataArray((np.arange(0, 7.5, 0.5)**2).reshape(3, 5),
    ...:                    dims=('x', 'y'))
    ...:                    

In [51]: arr.rolling(y=3, center=True).mean()
Out[51]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 5)>
array([[      nan,  0.416667,  1.166667,  2.416667,       nan],
       [      nan,  9.166667, 12.416667, 16.166667,       nan],
       [      nan, 30.416667, 36.166667, 42.416667,       nan]])
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y

In [52]: weight = xr.DataArray([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], dims=['window'])
    ...: arr.rolling(y=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)
    ...: 
Out[52]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 5)>
array([[   nan,  0.375,  1.125,  2.375,    nan],
       [   nan,  9.125, 12.375, 16.125,    nan],
       [   nan, 30.375, 36.125, 42.375,    nan]])
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
```

For the second example, you use [0.5, 1, 0.5] as weight, the total of which is 2. 
Therefore, the first non-nan item will be 
`(1 x 0.5) + (2 x 1) + (3 x 0.5) = 4`

If you want weighted mean, rather than the weighted sum, use [0.25, 0.5, 0.25] instead.

Comment: So the sum of the weight is important.
If I use a weight of [0.25, 0.5, 0.25] I go back to your original point that for evenly spaced data it is the same as the simple `mean`
`weight = xr.DataArray([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], dims=['window'])`
`da.rolling(x=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)` gives 2,3,4.
I think what I want is do the `sum` then divide by the length of the window
`weight = xr.DataArray([0.5, 1, 0.5], dims=['window']`
`da.rolling(x=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)/3` gives 1.33, 2, 2.66

Comment: Actually, the word `weighted rolling mean` in doc is not quite accurate. It is `weighted rolling sum`. If the weight is normalized, it will be mean.
`da.rolling(x=3, center=True).construct('window')` just returns a DataArray, so you can observe what is going on if `da.rolling(x=3, center=True).construct('window').dot(weight)` is called.