# How to apply a custom function on xarray's rolling window?

Tags: python-xarray

How can I apply a custom function on rolling windows from xarray DataArray?

For example, how can I achieve the following, but on DataArray instead?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))
d.rolling(10).apply(stats.median_absolute_deviation, raw=True)
```

**EDIT:**
I tried

```
d = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(100,3))
d.rolling(dim_0=10).reduce(np.mean)
```

and it works. But for `stats.median_absolute_deviation` it throws an error.

```
d = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(100,3))
d.rolling(dim_0=10).reduce(stats.median_absolute_deviation)
```

"ValueError: dimensions ('dim_0', 'dim_1') must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=0"

**EDIT 2**
I got it working using `mad` from `statsmodels` package:

```
d = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(100,3))
d.rolling(dim_0=10).reduce(statsmodels.robust.scale.mad)
```

so I guess there is a compatibility problem between `scipy.stats.median_absolute_deviation` and xarray.

Comment: You could try 'construct' method like proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512802/10062765

Comment: @kmuehlbauer I tried it and it gave me an error. Specifically when I used `stats.median_absolute_deviation`.